# Debugging Android native code with custom Android.mk build

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-studio, native

I'm trying to debug my Java/C++ library that has a custom Android.mk build configuration - not using the standard way through a single jniLibs folder. I created a dedicated debug configuration with all possible combinations of Debugger types - Auto, Native, Hybrid. I set the symbols folder like "myproject/lib/build/obj/local/armeabi-v7a" and "myproject/lib/build/obj/local". Debugger starts, my breakpoint appears with the proper "circle & check" icon but never gets hit!

Here's my config:

- Build tools 24.0.0
- SDK tools 24.0.0
- Android Studio 2.2P4
- physical Nexus 5X 6.0.1

Any ideas?

Comment: With the help of one guy from Google I've found out that the first and the main condition is to add argument `NDK_DEBUG=1` to `ndk-build` command. But it seems that in the newer versions of Android Studio which use LLDB instead of GDB this is not enough. It looks like the key is to use the new gradle notation `externalNdkBuild` but (as of 2.2.0-preview 5) it is not stable and finished enough.

Comment: Any updates? I'm also looking forward this feature

Comment: They claim since long time ago that it's officially working. But it doesn't for me.